# How is this (pencil like) design made?

Tags: software-recommendation, illustration, tools, fill

can anybody help me here to figure out how are these designs made? Like what software and what tools can be used to make similar designs?

[image: design 1]

[image: design 2]

Fish
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: These could be created in practically any drawing software you find, from free to most expensive. There's no "trick" or "magic" Someone merely drew the artwork. The same way you'd draw something on paper.

Comment: Even with nondrawing software like your browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nearly anything goes, but a vector drawing program is the easiest. I mean such as Illustrator, Inkscape, Affinity Designer, CorelDraw or Xara Designer. They have smoothed pencils and the pen for Bezier curves. Preset  curve drawing tools make regular  outlines such as ellipses, rectangles and circles easily. Drawing is possible even with a mouse.

Mouse is often very inaccurate. If you get exactly what the mouse outputs, you can get for ex. these:

[image]

Using smoothed pencil tool with a mouse gives easily these:

[image]

Of course you can in a vector program apply smoothing and make edits afterwards. Very trivial edits convert the results to these:

[image]

If you have a graphic tablet (Wacom etc...) you can get perfect looking curves with minimal edits in the first day you have it. When compared to a mouse a good graphic tablet lifts your drawing productivity hundreds of percents.

Illustrator maybe is a step ahead the rivals because it has perfectly working tools to fill areas which are limited by open curves and lines. Its Shape Builder is still the best. Think for ex the black wide stripes of the bee. They can be colored in a few seconds in Illustrator, no matter their borders were separate items, not carefully assembled closed paths like some other programs demand. Inkscape is free and it also has area filling tool (=the paint bucket) but it's very inaccurate. Affinity Designer hasn't even it.

Here is drawn some a little resembling shapes for the bee. This is in Inkscape:

[image]

The main body shape is a little crunched ellipse, the cheeks are circles, everything else has been drawn with the pen. The smoothed pencil would be handy for those numerous black lines in the wings, in the body, the feet and the antennas.

Your bee clearly has duplicated parts, for ex. the wings. The fish has plenty of them as a tiled pattern. Vector drawing programs have tools for making copies and tilings.

Vector drawing programs have steep learning curves. A beginner should get the documentation and patiently work the examples and available tutorials to get started. Trial and error is here extremely wasteful learning method.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for, how the hand drawing became so smooth. Last question, what tool the designer has used to fill this fish (I just added the fished in the main question description.)

Comment: @tri My guess: One coarse filled U is drawn with the pen or pencil. A couple of copies has been made and colored differently. Those three U's are aligned to the same horizontal line and that group is repeated to get one line of filled U's. That line is rotated to the wanted angle and a little shifted copies of it are made to get the fill pattern. The unnecessary U's are deleted. There are plenty of other possiblities, too, but the slight irregularity hints "no exact automatic tiling has been used"

Comment: @tri Oops a wrong fish. I'll check the right one.

Comment: @tri That fill can be a scaled copy of the main fish shape, no stroke, grey fill color. The dots are circles, ellipses or short lines, a rounded ending line type has been selected into use.

Comment: @tri Be aware that your examples are technically easy. The trick is to be able to imagine something as pretty and simple, but never before seen. Tinkering with software isn't the right way to develop that ability. A real pencil and paper are still a lightyear ahead.